# Python finding a specific value in a database

Tags: python, sql-server, database, web-applications

I am creating a web application login page where the user inputs their login information and the app will take their login information, compare it to what is in the database then determine if the login is a registered user.  I am starting off by doing a quick test to see if I can get the value from the database, however the problem I am having is that when I input the specific value form the user input that I want it to find, I keep getting an error stating that the value needs to be a specific parameter, row or tuple. I am using an sql server

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
if request.method == 'POST':
try:
connect = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL server};Server=localhost;Database=capstone;uid=;pwd=')
cursor = connect.cursor()
_username = str(request.form['username'])
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username= (%s)", _username)
dataUser = cursor.fetchone()[1]
 return(dataUser)
except Exception as e:
return (str(e))
```

Comment: You are testing with an SQL wildcard in the where condition. Use ? as a parameter marker instead of %s.

Comment: I have tried with ? and it still wouldn't work

Comment: Are you sure _username is not None?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways you can do this:

```
# using dictionary
values = {'username': _username, }
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=:username", values)

#using tuple:
values = (_username,)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=? ", values)
# Using fetchone will return the object and not an array.
# No need for [1] in 'cursor.fetchone()[1]'
return cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: neither of these options work, I still get this message: Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row.  It is weird because I try  cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='admin89'") and it does return the password